# failed to call a Python Script from PHP on Heroku platform(hosting)

Tags: php, heroku, shell-exec

i successfuly deployed my php app in Heroku platform. in my php code, i call Python file by shell_exec() as follows:

```
$result = shell_exec('python test.py ' . escapeshellarg($content));
```

my php app worked on localhost and there is no problem, the other functions of my php app worked on Heroku. But when i request the file which has this statement:

```
$result = shell_exec('python test.py ' . escapeshellarg($content));
```

the out put of python script is empty i.e echo $result; is empty.
to be more clear, if i run testpython.php on my localhost the output in browser after run $result = shell_exec('python test.py ' . escapeshellarg($content)); will be : results : "the output here from python script". but when i run testpython.php from Heroku hosting the result is empty
i checked if hosting supports shell_exec  function by :

```
is_callable('shell_exec') && false === stripos(ini_get('disable_functions'), 
'shell_exec');
```

and the result was true.
testpython.php is only run the python script on the shell and show the result in the browser.

If anyone may know the reason or have any comment/solution about that, it will be great to hear from him/her.

hint: I think the problem is that I am using some library in python script which is not available on Heroku server. is there a way to install python library (example nltk) on heroku server?

Comment: Is your test.py file in the same folder as the php file?

Comment: Your PHP error log will have more information

Comment: @reevkandari yes test.py file in the same folder as php file

Comment: Yeah as @iainn riggtly said. Check the logs. And revert back

Comment: @iainn i run , heroku logs , and i found this : "  syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in /app/testpython.php on line 16 ".....but the line 16 is work fine on localhost. the line 16 : $result = shell_exec('python test.py ' . escapeshellarg($content));

Comment: @reevkandari , error log didn't help to solve the problem!

Comment: When it says line 16 it means line 15. You have probably missed a semicolon at the 3nd of line 16.

Comment: thank you for your reply. now there is no message error, but the python script result is empty. to be more clear, if i run testpython.php on my localhost the out put in browser after run  $result = shell_exec('python test.py ' . escapeshellarg($content)); will be : results : "the output here from python script". but when i run  testpython.php from heroku hosting the result is empty

Comment: @reevkandari &&ainn,  I edited my question, please take a look~ thank you in advance

Comment: the last line of your question answers it maybe. have u installed the library by adding in to your requirements.txt?

Comment: @reevkandari i am new to Heroku platform. i tried to install it from requirements.txt as : pip install -r requirements.txt , then i get this message error :Collecting nltk==2.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nltk==3.4

Comment: since your code is sorted i suggest you go ahead with the heroku docs or support. you will probably solve it faster there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I guessed the problem was that I am using some library in python script which is not available on Heroku server. because my app is PHP so the default buildpacks is PHP. finally, i used Multiple Buildpacks(one for PHP and another for python) to solve all unavailable libraries on heroku server. and now my application perfectly work and php script call remote python script